# What's the difference between utf8_bin and latin1_general_cs

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For SQL, if I'm just using tables to store latin(or to be specific, just English) case sensitive strings, then will there be a difference between utf8_bin and latin1_general_cs?

Comment: You tag <sql> which is for ANSI SQL. Perhaps you should have used the <sql-server> tag?

Comment: have changed tags. thanks

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271676/should-latin-1-be-used-over-utf-8-when-it-comes-to-database-configuration

Answer (score 4):

If the characters you want to store are representable by Latin-1, then it won't make a difference for which characters you can store. What you're particularly talking about here are *collations*. When using the `latin1_general_cs` collation, that implies that the *charset* for the column is `latin1`. The same way the collation `utf8_bin` implies a charset of `utf8`.

Primarily you should decide on the *charset* you want to use, and for each charset you then have the choice of several *collations*. The collation influences how records are *sorted and compared*. `_bin` collations compare the raw binary representation of your text, i.e. only 100% equal values will be equal. Other collations like `_general_cs` apply language-aware sorting and comparison rules (e.g. `german` collations will sort and compare "ß" as close to "s"), and the `_cs` stands for *case sensitive*. A `_ci` collation would be *case insensitive*, meaning that "foo" and "Foo" compare as equal.

So, take your pick based on how you intend to use the column.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET` implies an encoding.  `ß` is encoded hex `DF` (1 byte) in latin1 and `C39F` (2 bytes) in utf8.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of *English* characters is the same in `latin1` and `utf8` (and most other `CHARACTER SETs` supported by MySQL).  So English text works identically between the charsets.

The two `COLLATIONs` will work the same.  For example `A` != `a` in either case.

Back to the question...

- For English, there is no difference.  If this is all you will ever have, then pick either one.
- For accented letters found in Europe, the encoding (`CHARACTER SET`) is different.  And the ordering of accented letters is different.
- For characters from the rest of the world -- You won't be able to store them in `latin1`, but you can store most of them in `utf8`.
- `latin1_bin` also gives you case sensitivity.  *For English*, it will be indistinguishable from `latin1_general_cs`.

The MySQL world is moving toward `utf8mb4`.